# Customer Edit Account Country Dropdown Issue Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

We have Upgrade Magento 2.2 to 2.3 now I am facing Issues in the customer edit section area.

https://prnt.sc/pwwmsy

In admin Edit Customer we check there dropdown is broken after Brazil country. I have also check all possibilities in General all Country Dropdown and others but not getting any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please open the below path file.

```
vendor/magento/module-customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component
```

open `customer_address_form.xml` and remove below code from line number.194

```
<formElements>
   <select>
       <settings>
           <options class="Magento\Directory\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection"/>
           </settings>
      </select>
 </formElements>
```

Remove the above code from the file and move this file to a local folder like below.

```
app/code/Magento/Customer/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml
```

After remove that you will see your selected country into customer address edit in M2.